# Component returned in map function will not render

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display items in a shopping cart. I made a "BagItem" component to display the information about the item, which comes from an object which is in the cart array in state, in redux. I also made a "Bag" component, which is where I map over the cart information and return the "BagItem" component.

Everything seems to be working with the map function. When I console.log the information in the BagItem component, I see all the properties I need to display. The problem is that in the Bag Component, the BagItem component will not render. When I load my webpage, I see the StoreNav and the subtotal text, but the BagItem component does not display.

I am very new to React and I'm sure there is something obvious I'm missing. I've been trying to figure it out all day, and I'd be very grateful for any help you can give.

BAG COMPONENT:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import StoreNav from "../store/StoreNav";
import BagItem from "../bag/BagItem";
import { getCart } from "../../ducks/reducer";


class Bag extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={} 
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.props.getCart()

  console.log(this.props.cart)
}

componentDidUpdate(){
  this.props.getCart()
}

render() {

const bagList =

 this.props.cart && this.props.cart.map(element => {
    console.log(this.props.cart)
  return   <BagItem 
  element={element}
  id={element.id}
  key= {`${element.id}${element.name}${element.price}${element.image}${element.size}${element.sleeves}${element.fabric}${element.length}`}
  name={element.name}
  image={element.image}
  size={element.size}
  price={element.price}
  sleeves={element.sleeves}
  fabric={element.fabric}
  length={element.length}

   />

})


return (
  <div>
    <StoreNav />
    {bagList}

    <p>Subtotal</p>


  </div>
);
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
  cart: state.cart
};
};

export default connect(
mapStateToProps,
{ getCart: getCart }
)(Bag);
```

BAGITEM COMPONENT

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { connect } from "react-redux";

 import "./bagitem.css";

 import { getCart } from "../../ducks/reducer";


  class BagItem extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getCart()
    console.log(this.props.cart[0][0].name)

  }

  render() {

return (
  <div className="bag-item-component-container">

    <div className="bag-item-component">

      <div className="bag-item-row1">
        <div>Size</div>
        <div>Quantity</div>
        <div>Price</div>
        <div>Remove</div>
      </div>
      {/* <div className="bag-item-row2">
    placeholder
    </div> */}
      <div className="bag-item-image-and-details-container">
        <div className="img1">
          <img className="item-image" alt="" src={this.props.cart[0][0].image} />
        </div>
        <div>{this.props.cart[0][0].name}
        <div className="details">
        <div>sleeves</div>
        <div>length</div>
        <div>fabric</div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
  }

 const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
  cart: state.cart
};
};

export default connect(
mapStateToProps,
{ getCart: getCart }
 )(BagItem);
```

Comment: One obvious thing is you're not invoking `{bagList}` - change to `{bagList()}`, Also move that function outside of the `render()` method...

Comment: Does `this.props.getCart()` triggers a re-render?

Comment: Also, use `react-devtools` extension to see what's was rendered in your app.

Comment: I checked the react-devtools and the BagItem component isn't being rendered. there is nothing between the StoreNav and the subtotal. I'll see if I can figure out if this.props.getCart is re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a function to `bagList`. So, you should call it or you can pass the rendered components to that variable.

```js
const bagList = this.props.cart && this.props.cart.map(element => <BagItem ... />)
```

Read: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally you do not need to separate your BagItem render. and you already pass element props so use element props inside the BagItem .

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import StoreNav from "../store/StoreNav";
import BagItem from "../bag/BagItem";
import { getCart } from "../../ducks/reducer";


class Bag extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={} 
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.props.getCart()

  console.log(this.props.cart)
}

componentDidUpdate(){
  this.props.getCart()
}

render() {

return (
  <div>
    <StoreNav />
     {
    this.props.cart && this.props.cart.map(element => (
    <BagItem 
    element={element}
    id={element.id}
    key= {element.id}
     />}))
    <p>Subtotal</p>


  </div>
);
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
  cart: state.cart
};
};

export default connect(
mapStateToProps,
{ getCart: getCart }
)(Bag);
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it to work by changing the child component (BagItem) so that it's not receiving the cart props from redux, but instead is just receiving them from the parent component (Bag). I had to make sure to bring props in through the constructor. Here is the revised BagItem component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import "./bagitem.css";

 // import { getCart } from "../../ducks/reducer";


 class BagItem extends Component {
 constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={}
 }

// componentDidMount(){
//     this.props.getCart()
//     console.log(this.props.cart[0][0].name)

// }

  render() {
      console.log(this.props.element)

return (
  <div className="bag-item-component-container">

    <div className="bag-item-component">

      <div className="bag-item-row1">
        <div>Size</div>
        <div>Quantity</div>
        <div>Price</div>
        <div>Remove</div>
      </div>
      {/* <div className="bag-item-row2">
    placeholder
    </div> */}
      <div className="bag-item-image-and-details-container">
        <div className="img1">
          <img className="item-image" alt="" src={this.props.element.image} />
        </div>
        <div>{this.props.element.name}
        <div className="details">
        <div>sleeves: {this.props.element.sleeves}</div>
        <div>length: {this.props.element.length}</div>
        <div>fabric {this.props.element.fabric}</div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
);
}
 }

 // const mapStateToProps = state => {
 //     return {
 //       cart: state.cart
//     };
 //   };

 //   export default connect(
//     mapStateToProps,
//     { getCart: getCart }
//   )(BagItem);


export default BagItem
```